# Gevent Pool doesnt seem to improve perfromance

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, gevent

I have a list with 9 million http links they are stored in `lt`

For a minimally reproducible [example](https://pastebin.com/iANfM2yN):

I wrote this initially

```
cat = []
i=0
for l in lt:
    print(i)
    if re.search('.+videoStory.+', l):
        print('video')
        cat.append('video')
    else:
        response=requests.get(l,headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36', })
        if response.status_code == 200:
            bs = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('ascii', 'ignore'),'lxml')
            cat.append(bs.findAll('div', {'class':'ArticleHeader_channel_4KD-f'})[0].text)
        elif response.status_code == 404:
            print('404')
            cat.append('404')
        elif response.status_code == 500:
            print('500')
            cat.append('500')
        else:
            print(response.status_code)
            break
    i+=1
```

`bs.findAll('div', {'class':'ArticleHeader_channel_4KD-f'})[0].text` extracts the category of the page.

This code successfully completes 3 links in 1 second that would mean to get 9 million it would take 34.7 days  (tested this by taking only 5000 links took 27 minutes or so)

```
p = pool.Pool(1000)
yo= []
jobs=[]

def get_link(ul):
    if re.search('.+videoStory.+', ul):
        yo.append('video')
    else:
        r = requests.get(ul, headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36', })
        if r.status_code == 200:
            bs = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode('ascii', 'ignore'),'lxml')
            crap = bs.findAll('div', {'class':'ArticleHeader_channel_4KD-f'})[0].text
            yo.append(crap)
        elif r.status_code == 404:
    #        print('404')
            yo.append('404')
        elif r.status_code == 500:
    #        print('500')
            yo.append('500')

startTime= datetime.now() 
for yum in lt:
     jobs.append(p.apply_async(get_link, args =(yum,)))

gevent.joinall(jobs)
timeElapsed=datetime.now()-startTime 
print('Time elpased (hh:mm:ss.ms) {}'.format(timeElapsed))
```

This code successfully completes 5 links in 1 second that would mean to get 9 million it would take 20.8 days (tested this by taking only 5000 links took 16 minutes or so)

This is till taking too long.

Should try setting `concurrency` to `10000`, would that help?(maybe Reuters won't allow so many concurrently)

Should I be trying Parallel Processing?

Answer (score 1):

Given the information, you should be able to run multiple instances of your code, which start from different positions in the list.

Say you run 5 instances of the code, each having responsibility of going through 5,000 links. So, in one run, you cover 25,000 links. That's around 30 minutes for you.

Say, instance #1 runs for links 1-5000, when its list is exhausted, it should start from 25,001th link. So, for every instance, you have to iterate it to run from `where_it_left + 25000`th link.

Let's see the math here. Simple example:
`5,000,000 links / 25,000 = 200 runs.
200 * 0.5 hour = 100 hours (~ 4-5 days)`

You can even reduce this further if you can run more than 5 instances of code at one time.

Another better way is to use some web-scraping software like **HTTrack**. But, you might have to do a lot of configurations in it to get the results according to your needs.